# Entity Framework Pending Requests Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4, transactions, backgroundworker

Im building a multi-user application using EF4. One user is making changes and the other users cannot see the changes, so my workaround was :

**1.** I made a table inside my DB, and a view to it (RecentUpdates) that gets the last 20 seconds worth of changes made by all users (including ones own changes).

**2.** I retrieve the latest changes inside a background worker thread (every 15 seconds) and try and update the local data that has changed :

```
    private void dbUpdater_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
                var recentUpdates = Helper.Ctx.RecentUpdates;
                foreach (RecentUpdate ru in recentUpdates)
                {
                    switch (ru.Table)
                    {
                        case "Trailers":
                            Helper.Ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, Helper.Ctx.Trailers.Where(x => x.Id == ru.Id));
                            break;
                        case "Bookings":
                            Helper.Ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, Helper.Ctx.Bookings.Where(x => x.Id == ru.Id));
                            Helper.Ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, Helper.Ctx.Planner.Where(x => x.Id == ru.Id));
                            break;
                        case "Works":
                            Helper.Ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, Helper.Ctx.Works.Where(x => x.Id == ru.Id));
                            break;
                        case "Requests":
                            Helper.Ctx.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, Helper.Ctx.Requests.Where(x => x.Id == ru.Id));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
        }
    }
```

**3.** The user is making changes, and the background thread is receiving, sometimes it causes errors like :

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Commit. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Commit()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
   at CAPS.fMain.dgvBookings_CellClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

**And also :**

```
************** Exception Text **************

System.Data.EntityException: An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)

   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)

   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)

   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginTransaction()

   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)

   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()

   at CAPS.fMain.dgvBookings_CellClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

**I feel its some sort of collision, trying to access the same db at the same time. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like lock in sql server. Many users are trying to get same resource at the same time. Catch an exception, wait and try again.

You can also write your own select procedures for example `WITH NOLOCK` or `READ UNCOMITED` and use them in EF. But this can cause dirty reads etc.

Comment: Is there no simple fix from within c#?

Comment: i don't think so because it's sql server level error... If you are querying table so often, it's normal that you have to do something with concurency.

Comment: It can't be a lock because commits don't acquire or wait on locks.